# Flutter spinkitcircle controller

Tags: flutter, animation, widget, visibility, hidden

Please help me to fix this problem,
After adding these code, I get an error on (this)
just (this). shows error:
SpinKitSquareCircle(
color: Colors.red,
size: 50.0,
controller: AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1200))

Comment: in this line just (this) has error, (vsync: this,duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1200))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.